# How do I create a table for JOptionPane within a loop?

Tags: java

Ok so I have to write a program to convert lbs to kilograms and my professor wants both input and output in joption pane. This is what my code looks like so far:

```
package weightTest;
//import DecimalFormat; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
public class weightTestClass
{



    enter code here
    public static void main(String [] args)

        {
        int startingPounds = 0; 
        int endingPounds = 0;
        startingPounds = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the starting weight in pounds"));
        endingPounds= Integer.parseInt(JOp tionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the end weight in pounds"));

        //Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        //int startingPounds= kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nPounds || Kilograms");
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        if(startingPounds>endingPounds)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you have an invalid value");
            //System.out.println("you have an invalid value");
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=startingPounds;i<=endingPounds; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("");

                //System.out.print(i+" lb" + "         " + i*0.454+" kg");

            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i+" lb" + "         " + i*0.454+" kg");
            //  System.out.println("the weight in kilograms is "+ kilograms);



        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, Ive commented out the system.out because the code runs fine with it but as soon as i put joptionpane, it has to iterate each time in the loop, and i asked my professor he said I have to make a table and put the joption outside the loop. How do I do this?

Comment: What is your question ? How to create a table of all results ? or How to add that table to a `JOptionpane` ? Try to ask one question at a time.

Comment: i need to add the table to JOptionPane, sorry

Comment: I do not a table in your code.  You need to create a `JTable`  : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html